# Correctly display special characters in JSON API response using nodeFetch

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, special-characters

I have a react app that communicates with a RESTful API over HTTP.
The API returns a JSON response body that may contain special characters.

An example response may look like this:

```
{
    "name": "Property One",
    "description": "Res Thick Film 0805 49.9 Ohm 1% 0.25W(1/4W) ±100ppm/°C Pad SMD Automotive T/R",
    ...
}
```

With the special characters in question being (but not limited to) ± and °.

I perform the request using `nodeFetch` like so:

```
nodeFetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers }).then(response => response.json());
```

If I observe the object after it has been deserialised using `response.json()`, the `description` property now looks like this:

```
"Res Thick Film 0805 49.9 Ohm 1% 0.25W(1/4W) �100ppm/�C Pad SMD Automotive T/R"
```

How do I stop the special characters getting replaced with �?

Comment: seems like `nodeFetch`handles utf-8 automatically. Do you have any control over the REST server? Can you set it to encode its response in utf-8? `'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: @DSCH I do have access. Changed the `Content-Type` to `application/json; charset=UTF-8` and `nodeFetch` correctly deserialised the response! Answer the question so I can award the bounty!

Comment: which version of nodefetch are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should set the the header: `Content-Type` to `text/html; charset=utf8`. `nodeFetch` supports `UTF-8` out of the box

Comment: If the version of `nodeFetch` is `2.X` then doing the change on server side should not be required at all. Not sure what version OP is using though

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at this issue, probably cskau-g repost should help you 
https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175

I think the issue is with encoding to utf-8 and content type must be set to text/html